# In the USA, is there any difference in the scope and meanings of the terms lawyer and attorney?

Tags: united-states, legal-terms, lawyer

Or are they fully anonymous and interchangeable? It seems to me that they are, while lawyer is simply the more colloquial and less formal term.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the U.S. the two terms are basically interchangeable as they refer to members of the same profession. The term attorney emphasizes a lawyer's role as an agent of the client. The term lawyer emphasizes the professional's legal expertise. But they both refer to the same thing.

Unlike many countries, the U.S. does not have multiple legal professions to any meaningful extent (yes, there are a small number of patent lawyers and tax litigation practitioners who are not also regular lawyers, and yes there are limited practice lawyers in a few states, but both are negligible in terms of number of legal professionals). In the U.S., transactional lawyers, trial lawyers, prosecutors, and judges, for example, are all members of the same licensed profession.

In contrast, England has barristers and solicitors. Similarly, in many civil law countries there are legally trained notaries who do transactional work, trial lawyers roughly equivalent to barristers, prosecutors, and judges, all of which are separately regulated professions, and there are also large number of people who work in business or government who went to law school but are not admitted to any licensed legal profession (somewhat akin to U.S. professionals who were business majors who have degrees in finance or business management).

Comment: And on the side of all that sit the Paralegals.

Comment: Anyone who holds themselves out as a patent lawyer better be both admitted to the bar somewhere in the US and be a registered practitioner with the USPTO. I’m a registered practitioner but not an attorney which makes me a patent agent not a specialized, limited lawyer.

Comment: A patent agent, IMHO, is a licensed legal occupation parallel to that of an attorney in the U.S., in a way analogous to that of other countries that have multiple licensed legal professions to carry out the functions mostly carried out by a single licensed legal profession in the U.S. Patent agents are also certainly a specialized profession, even if they are not really "limited lawyers".